# I can't access to the protected member of my base class

Tags: c++, protected

I am new at programming using c++ and having some troubles creating my constructors & objects.
How can I access to my protected members like int p_iID in the Fahrzeug class?
I have to access them for both of my objects seperately.

I would be so happy if you could help me out with this.

```
class Fahrzeug {
private:
    
protected:
    string p_sName;
    int p_iID;
    double p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;
    double p_dGesamtStrecke;
    double p_dGesamtZeit;
    double p_dZeit;
public:
    virtual void vAusgeben(Fahrzeug* pFahrzeug1,Fahrzeug* pFahrzeug2);
    virtual void vKopf();
    virtual void vSimulieren(Fahrzeug *pFahrzeug, Fahrzeug *pFahrzeug2);
class PKW;

class PKW: public Fahrzeug{
PKW(const int p_iMaxID, string p_sName, double p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit, double p_dGesamtStrecke) {
    p_iID = p_iMaxID;
    this->p_sName = p_sName;
    this->p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit = (p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit < 0) ? 0 : p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;
    this->p_dGesamtStrecke = p_dGesamtStrecke;
}
    void vAusgeben(PKW pkw1, PKW pkw2) {
    cout << "\n";
    PKW pkw1;
    PKW pkw2;
    pkw1.vKopf();

    cout << setw(5) << left << pkw1.p_iID<< " " << setw(10) <<pkw1.p_sName << setw(8) << " "    << setw(15) << showpoint << pkw1.p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit << setw(3) << " " << pkw1.p_dGesamtStrecke; //Here I have the issue with pkw1.p_sName
    cout << "\n";
    cout << setw(5) << left << pkw2.p_iID << " " << setw(10) << pkw2.p_sName << setw(8) << " " << setw(15) << showpoint << pkw2.p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit << setw(3) << " " << pkw2.p_dGesamtStrecke;
    cout << "\n";

}
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you get? Also, why is `vAusgeven` creating two new variables with the exact same names as its arguments, thus hiding them?

Comment: Also, you should probably create a constructor for `Fahrzeug` that `PKW` can delegate to.

Comment: Also also, that `p_` prefix is really useless in the world of syntax highlighting and "go to definition".

Comment: Ewww, *two* dialects of Hungarian layered on top of one another.  The pain... the pain....

Comment: For minimal repro, you can use only one member variable and one function...

Comment: On third notice, is the problem that your `PKW::vAusgeben` is not a suitable override for `Fahrzeug::vAusgeven`?

Comment: You can only access protected members of `*this`, not of an arbitrary object. You need to rethink your design. (It is pretty odd for a non-static member function not to use `*this` in any way. What is the purpose of this function?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void vAusgeben(PKW pkw1, PKW pkw2) {
```

You probably don't want to pass your `PKW` objects by value (or expect [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)). Pass const references instead:

```
void vAusgeben(const PKW& pkw1, const PKW& pkw2) {
```

Also, why are you [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your 2 parameters with these local variables?

```
PKW pkw1; // ???
PKW pkw2; // ???
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the issues raised in comments (and in another answer), there's a special rule for protected members that sometimes surprises people. An object of a derived type can access protected members of its base sub-object, but it can't access protected members of some other object. So:

```
struct B {
protected:
    int i;
};

struct D : B {
    void f(const B&);
};

void D::f(const B& b) {
    i = 3;   // okay, accessing my own protected member
    b.i = 3; // no, access to protected member of different object not allowed
}
```

In the code in the question, the function `PKW::vAusgeben` can access its own copies of `p_sName`, `p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit`, and `p_dGesamtStrecke`, but it can't access `pkw1.p_sName`, `pkw1.p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit`, or `pkw1.p_dGesamtStrecke`.